# Array- keep track of number of frequency from user input

Tags: java, arrays

I planned a simple program that would take 10 `int` from the user and if the user enters the same number, it would be added to a new `array` called Frequency.

For example, the user enters `[1,5,2,1,5,7,8,4,5,9]` , the frequency array would be `[2,3,1,2,3,1,1,1,3,1]`.

Here's what I've tried so far but I am not succeeding to complete this.

```
int[] arr = new int [10];
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++)
  {
     System.out.println("Enter upto 10 numbers:");
     arr[i] = s.nextInt();
  }
  int[] freq = new int[10];
  for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
  {
    //Frequency Method    
  }


public static int frequency(int[] total)
{
  int count = 0;
     // lost from here 

  }
  return count;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the static method, I would modify so that it takes an `int[] total` and `int value` and in the method, create a new `int` called counter that has value of 0 and make a for-loop that iterates through `int[] total` and compares if `int[i] total == value` and if it does, you increase the counter by one and `return` the counter.

Once you have frequency done, make another for loop to iterate through array with user input and in the for loop, add `freq[i] = frequency(arr, arr[i]);` which will add repetitive numbers in the frequency array.

Comment: Appreciate you not posting code. Will try this and give you an update

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is the one-line solution using Java streams:

```
int[] freq = Arrays.stream(arr).map(x->(int)Arrays.stream(arr).filter(y->x==y).count()).toArray();
```